# How to implement checkbox and select option in datatables?

Tags: ajax, onclick, datatables, onchange

I populate the table with an ajax call. In the first column I have checkboxes for selecting and deselecting rows and submit data to a php script. I have also two columns with select fields. 
The render function for the one (of the two) column with select:

```
{
  targets: 6,
  render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
  if(data.length == 4) {
  return '<select class="form-control" id="selectotpionmonths' + data[0].cataloguenumber + '"><option value="'+ data[3].months 
              + '">' + data[3].months + '<option value="'+ data[2].months 
              + '">' + data[2].months + '<option value="'+ data[1].months 
              + '">' + data[1].months + '<option value="'+ data[0].months 
              + '">' + data[0].months + '</select>';
            } else {
              return data[0].months;
            }
    }
},
```

And the handler for click event and on change event:

```
$('#results tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

      // Get row data
      var data = table.row($row).data();

      $('#selectotpionmonths' + data['enc_unit']).change(function(){

        e.preventDefault();

        var selectedoptionformonths = $('#selectotpionmonths' + data['enc_unit']).find("option:selected").text();            

        if(selectedoptionformonths == 3) {

          $('#selectoptionprice' + data['enc_unit']).find('option[value="' + data['price_rrp'][3].price + '"]').prop('selected', true);

        } else if(selectedoptionformonths == 6) {

          $('#selectoptionprice' + data['enc_unit']).find('option[value="' + data['price_rrp'][2].price + '"]').prop('selected', true);

        } else if(selectedoptionformonths == 9) {              

          $('#selectoptionprice' + data['enc_unit']).find('option[value="' + data['price_rrp'][1].price + '"]').prop('selected', true);

        } else if(selectedoptionformonths == 12) {              

         $('#selectoptionprice' + data['enc_unit']).find('option[value="' + data['price_rrp'][0].price + '"]').prop('selected', true);

        }
      });

      if(data['price_numberofmonths'].length == 4) {
        var monthsoption = $('#selectotpionmonths' + data['enc_unit']).find("option:selected").text();           
        var priceoption = $('#selectoptionprice' + data['enc_unit']).find("option:selected").text();        
      } else {
        var monthsoption = data['price_numberofmonths'][0].months;
        var priceoption = data['price_rrp'][0].price;
      }

      // Get row ID
      var dataforserver = {name: data['enc_unit'], duration: monthsoption, price: priceoption};
      var rowId = dataforserver.name;

      // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs 
      var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

      // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
      if(this.checked && index === -1){
         rows_selected.push(rowId);
         units_selected.push(dataforserver);
      // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
      } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1){
         rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
         units_selected.splice(index, 1);
      }

      if(this.checked){
         $row.addClass('selected');
      } else {
         $row.removeClass('selected');
      }

      order_total = 0;
      for(i=0; i < units_selected.length; i++) {
          order_total += parseFloat(units_selected[i].price);
        }
      //console.log(order_total.toFixed(2));
      $( "#ukhoanswer" ).html(

        "Number of units selected: " + units_selected.length + "<br/>" + 
        "Total cost of order: " + order_total.toFixed(2)
      );

      // Update state of "Select all" control
      updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
   $('#results').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function(e){
      $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
   });

   // Handle click on "Select all" control
   $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table.table().container()).on('click', function(e){
      if(this.checked){
         $('#results tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
      } else {
         $('#results tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
      }

      // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

You may view the initial code for the checkboxes [here](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/)

When I click on the cell with the select field I want to prevent the click event on the row. I have tried adding e.preventDefault but with no success. For the columns with the select option I want only the change event to be triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: e.stopPropagation() in the click handler?

Comment: I tried it. No success.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
      var selectField = $('.form-control');
      selectField.on('click', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
      });
```

The selector are for the cells with the select options. Now the first time that I click on the select field the row is selected. But next time I select an option the click event is prevented and the row is not selected/deselected.

I am looking on how to prevent the row being selected on the first click on a select field.